# Usage of Pyserial and Pexpect in Windows

Tags: python, windows, pyserial, pexpect

I have a script which functions perfectly in Ubuntu, however my desire is to get this working on a Windows machine for use in a Production environment. The general purpose of this script is to program a PCB.

I am having issues both researching and adapting this section of the code:

```
try: 
  fd = serial.Serial(Port, Baud) #Opens the specified port
  child = pexpect.fdpexpect.fdspawn(fd, timeout=180)
except:
  input('There has been an error making the connection, check your connections and try again\nPress enter to exit')
  sys.exit()
input('Press enter to continue, then apply 24V power to the unit')
```

The issue being with:

```
child = pexpect.fdpexpect.fdspawn(fd, timeout=180)
```

Any advice or modifications are much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be some differences for Windows. 
PySerial does not have fileno on it.

Based on [this github issue](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/issues/197) you could try using something like this:

```
import os
import pexpect.fdpexpect
port = "COM5"
reader = pexpect.fdpexpect.fdspawn(os.open(port, os.O_RDWR))
```